# I always get this error. what should i do?

Tags: c#

The database `'C:\USERS\ROANEPC\DESKTOP\FINAL\BROADCASTWEB\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF'` cannot be opened because it is version `661`. This server supports version `655` and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
Could not open new database `'C:\USERS\ROANEPC\DESKTOP\FINAL\BROADCASTWEB\APP_DATA\ASPNETDB.MDF'`. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file `C:\Users\RoanePC\Desktop\Final\BroadcastWeb\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF` failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Answer (score 0):

Database version:

```
655 means SQL Server 2008 instance. 
661 means SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.
684 means SQL Server 2012 CTP1 instance.
706 means SQL Server 2012 instance.
782 means SQL Server 2014 instance.
```

You'll need to install the R2 version and continue to use that version. Downgrades do not work as in your example from 2008 R2 (10.50) to 2008 (10.00) but you can upgrade versions.

Comment: i used sql server 2014. is it okay?

Comment: Doesn't seem so that its using 2014.

Comment: @KatherineJaneL.Pleños- please check if your project is using Sql Server Express.

Comment: can you still connect to teamviewer?

Comment: i can try and check

Comment: using still the same id?